# Visual Studio Online build fails due to stale submodules OR How to update submodules before build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am setting up a VSTS build online. My source includes a dependent submodule. 
When I set up the build definition, I selected check out submodules:

[image]

However, this does not pull the latest version (`HEAD`) in the submodule's repository.  It seems to be pulling the version of the submodule that corresponds to when I created the submodule.

So I added a build task to execute 
    `git submodule update --remote`
but this fails  with this error

```
2017-08-27T01:17:39.1000559Z fatal: could not read Username for 'https://[myaccount].visualstudio.com': No error
2017-08-27T01:17:39.1580556Z Unable to fetch in submodule path 'The SubModule'
2017-08-27T01:17:39.1803843Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2017-08-27T01:17:39.1840570Z ##[section]Finishing: Update sub modules
```

How can I get the latest version of the submodule, either in the build settings or via a task?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -

1. execute   `git submodule update --remote` on my local machine. That will update the submodule locally as well as the .gitmodules file.
2. Check in the updates
3. Execute the build and it will work fine, no need for any other scripts.

Comment: Right.  A submodule is added at a current commit - any time you want to update to a newer version of the submodule, you will need to do the update and commit those changes.  Submodules do not get automatically updated to reflect the remote repository.  And you _definitely_ should not do this inside the build, that would get your CI builds out of sync with your local builds.